# extend authentication to a sub folder which is using a different php framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, symfony, authentication

I'm using Codeigniter for my main project which also contains a sub-folder that has another project in Symfony (Kimai). I would like to use a single sign-in both in my main project (CodeIgniter) and the sub-folder (Symfony).

Both of these frameworks' auth mechanisms differ. What I want is that whenever a user authenticates into my main project, my Symfony project shouldn't need to ask for the auth again.

What I've tried so far:

I tried using `curl` to make auth.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is write custom Authenticator for symfony, which will validate againts your data in your main application, which is CodeIgniter.

In general you might have few different approaches how to implement it

- Authenticator is authenticating against some API from your main app
- Authenticator reads information directly from database of your main app
- Some mixture of that, with session / cookies etc (depens on your setup).

Example how to write custom authenticator in Symfony is in [symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html). This is clean way how to implement it in symfony without any hacks etc.